# hashing overflow and underflow in RobertSedwick book

Tags: c, algorithm, hash

> <1>If the keys are w-bit integers, we can convert them to
>   floating-point numbers and divide by 2 to <2>power of w to get
>   floating-point numbers between 0 and 1, then multiply by M.
>
> <3>If floating-point operations are expensive and the numbers are not
>   so large as to cause <4>overflow, we can accomplish the same result
>   with integer arithmetic operations: Multiply the key <5>by M, then
>   shift right w bits to divide by 2 to power of w (or, if the multiply
>   would overflow, <6>shift then multiply). Such functions are not useful
>   for hashing unless the keys are evenly <7>distributed in the range,
>   because the hash value is determined only by the leading digits of the
>   <8>keys.

I am reading about hasing in Robert Sedwick book in Algorithms in C++

Here M is size of hash container for eg container[M]

1. My question on above text is what author is talking about overflow and underflow at line 4 in this context? Here author is talking about if the multiply would oveflow , shift then multiply? What to shift and what to multiply
2. Request to understand lines 3 to 8 with simple example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer multiplication has the possibility to overflow and lose information, e.g. an example which overflows when performing 32-bit unsigned arithmetic:

```
2 ^ 31 = 0x80000000
(2 ^ 31 * 2 ^ 31) = 2 ^ 62 = 0x4000000000000000
```

Since the largest number representable in 32 bits is `0xFFFFFFFF = 2 ^ 32 - 1`, the result of the above calculation would be 0, since the bits above 32 bits are lost.

Comment: can you please answer second question from hasing point of view. I have modified my question can you please answer Thanks

Comment: I don't understand where graphs come into this?